# Uncertainty from equation involving fitted parameters

Tags: standard-deviation, error, fitting, uncertainty

I want to estimate the uncertainty of a calculation which involves a quantity from a fitted mathematical model. More specifically, the end calculation would be something like:

P = x / A_tot

where I know the uncertainty of the x quantity. Given the uncertainty of A_tot I could then estimate the uncertainty of P with standard error propagation techniques. The problem is that A_tot is given not by experiments but comes from a fitted model with the following form:

[image: equation 1]

where f(r) is a Gaussian distribution:

[image: fr]

rp and sp are the fitted parameters, for which I have the confidence intervals, and r the independent variable.

From my model I only get a value of A_tot, which is that obtained with the best guess of my parameters. How can I estimate the uncertainty of the value of Atot so that I could use it in my final error estimation? Or should I consider it as a constant?

Comment: Because the numerator is always infinite--the integral diverges towards $+\infty$ at the lower limit--it's difficult to proceed except to reply something like "the uncertainty is always infinite" or "this makes no sense at all."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have editted the question and hope it's more clear now.

Comment: There must still be something wrong with your statement of the model, because the numerator is always divergent, no matter what the fitted parameters may be.

Comment: well the model is widely used in the literature. I take it that this model doesn't allow for an uncertainty calculation of its results then.Thank you.

Comment: I urge you to make a detailed comparison of the formula you have presented and what you find in the literature.  I doubt there is any literature on a model that cannot exist mathematically!

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that the upper limit of infinity is obviously defined as a finite number when solving it numerically. The idea is to represent up to the highest radius, which is what r stands for. Here is one of the many papers that uses this model https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9673(00)00420-9, equation 9.

Comment: The problem is not with the upper limit: it's with the *lower* limit.  There, $f$ approaches a finite number while $2/r$ diverges and introduces a divergent logarithmic term into the integral.  Because your reference is behind an expensive firewall, and its abstract provides no information at all about its model, it isn't of any use here.  Do you think you could provide a link to an accessible paper?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any reference without a paywall. What if the lower limit is not 0... would it be possible then to estimate an uncertainty?

Comment: Sure.  I would worry about the results being extremely sensitive to the lower limit, though.  That would depend on the values of the fitted parameters--if they place very little probability near $r=0,$ things should be ok.